# Wordpress page loads but all content invisible

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am at my wits end trying to work out what is going on with my site page. On the desktop, full screen, my page loads and displays without issue. In fact the page tests just fine and there are no errors appearing in FireBug console. If I resize my browser window to about have screen size and refresh the page, or load one of the other pages on the site, the page appears to load but all content is invisible. Firebug shows all of the code is correctly loaded, scroll bar appear to show that the content is larger than the window and if I use the firebug content inspector when I move the mouse over the page various sections highlight but everything is white (i.e. invisible). If I then resize the window to make it larger all the content suddenly appears.

I made a video to demonstrate at this link: [DropBox page load video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xn6087ye20ezefq/Optimum-Theme-Issue-1080p.mov?dl=0)

The page will not display at all on mobile devices, although again the scroll bars appear which indicates that the content is there but just invisible.

If you want to try yourself the URL is http://sounusual.com

Has anyone experienced this problem before? What could cause it and how could I resolve it?

A bit of background. The site is using Wordpress. The problem is definitely linked to the template being used. Template appears to have been created by an amateur. He is attempting to resolve some of the issues I am having but seems to be balking at this one so I may end up having to fix it myself but am unsure where to start looking.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a little on your website and the source of the problem seems to be the div wrapper for the main content containing the *.page-transition* class:

```
<div class="page-transition" ...
```

That class has the opacity set to 0:

```
.page-transition {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    ...
```

When the device size is above 1200px, that div gets additional *.pageTransitionEnd* class which sets the opacity to 1:

```
.page-transition.pageTransitionEnd {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So you need to figure it out what adds .pageTransitionEnd class and why it doesn't work on device widths of less than 1200px.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Found the code when .pageTransitionEnd class was added and removed the test for screen width and now the page loads without issue on all devices and window sizes. I will now go back to the developer and find out what he was thinking when writing that code.